# No bean named '' is defined

Tags: java, spring, aop

I am testing out simple AOP use case in Spring but am getting the below error,

> Exception in thread "main"
>    org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>    bean named 'bean1' is defined

Below are my source files,

1. DemoConfig.java

   ```
   package com.luv2code.aopdemo;
   import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Qualifier;
   import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
   import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
   import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
   import org.springframework.context.annotation.EnableAspectJAutoProxy;

   import com.luv2code.aopdemo.aspect.MyDemoLoggingAspect;
   import com.luv2code.aopdemo.dao.AccountDAO;

   @Configuration
   @EnableAspectJAutoProxy
   @ComponentScan("com.luv2code.aopdemo")
   public class DemoConfig {

       @Bean
       @Qualifier("bean1")
       public AccountDAO accDao() {
           return new AccountDAO();
       }

       @Bean
       @Qualifier("bean2")
       public MyDemoLoggingAspect myAscpect() {
           return new MyDemoLoggingAspect();
       }
   }
   ```
2. MyDemoLoggingAspect.java

   ```
    package com.luv2code.aopdemo.aspect;

    import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Aspect;
    import org.aspectj.lang.annotation.Before;

    @Aspect
    public class MyDemoLoggingAspect {

       // this is where we add all of our related advices for logging  
       // let's start with an @Before advice
       @Before("execution(** com.luv2code.aopdemo.dao.AccountDAO.addAccount(..))")
       public void beforeAddAccountAdvice() {  
           System.out.println("\n=====>>> Executing @Before advice on addAccount()");

       }
    }
   ```
3. MainDemoApp.java

   ```
   package com.luv2code.aopdemo;

   import com.luv2code.aopdemo.dao.AccountDAO;

   public class MainDemoApp {

       public static void main(String[] args) {
           // read spring config java class
           AnnotationConfigApplicationContext context = new AnnotationConfigApplicationContext(DemoConfig.class);          
           // get the bean from spring container
           AccountDAO theAccountDAO = context.getBean("bean1", AccountDAO.class);
           // call the business method
           theAccountDAO.addAccount();
           // do it again!
           System.out.println("\nlet's call it again!\n");
           // call the business method again
           theAccountDAO.addAccount();     
           // close the context
           context.close();
       }
   }
   ```

I have given my bean ID "bean1", even after that Spring is not able to find my bean in the context. Why am I getting this error and how to resolve this?

Answer (score 5):

The `@Qualifier` tag is used with the `@Autowired` annotation.

What you need is

```
@Bean(name="bean1")
public AccountDAO accDao() {
    return new AccountDAO();
}
```